# Are linearly dependent random variables necessarily correlated?

Tags: random-variables, covariance

'Random variables that are uncorrelated are not necessarily independent, since they can be dependent in non-linear ways' So does this mean that a linearly dependent random variables are necessarily correlated?

Comment: Almost. The correlation coefficient, *if it is defined*, is $1$ or $-1$. But it could be undefined. Let $X$ be say standard normal, and let $Y=0$. Then $Y$ is a linear function of $X$, but the correlation coefficient is undefined. Or else suppose that the variance of $X$ is undwfined, and let $Y=2X$. Then the correlation coefficient does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Note that "dependent" in probability theory and linear algebra have quite different meanings.  But as for your question, $X$ and $0$ are linearly dependent and uncorrelated.